# Thorntail microprofile dependency

Tags: thorntail

looking at the Thorntail Project Generator I can see that it includes all the specific Microprofile extensions (health/load balancing/tracing...) and also includes this fraction:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
      <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is this dependency equivalent to including **all** single microprofile fractions in the project?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `microprofile` fraction is meant to bring in all fractions that are required for supporting the entire [MicroProfile Platform](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/architecture.asciidoc).

Thorntail currently doesn't support any *standalone* MicroProfile specification (standalone specs are specs developed in the MicroProfile project, but are not part of the MicroProfile Platform; one example is MP Reactive Messaging). If there were fractions that implement these standalone specs, they would *not* be brought in by the `microprofile` fraction. But that's currently a theoretical question, as there are none.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying on this stuff. Much appreciated!